# Using separate thread pools for normal and scheduled tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, scheduledexecutorservice

Suppose I already have an application-wide `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and now I also need a `ScheduledExecutorService`. Should I just change the implementation to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and use that for both, scheduled and ordinary tasks? Or should I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` for ordinary tasks, and a separate `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for scheduled tasks? Is it a good idea to use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` for ordinary tasks, or is there something in it's implementation that makes it only useful for scheduled tasks?

My line of thinking is that a single `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` would allow for the best thread usage, while it increases the risk of starvation if we have many scheduled tasks and few ordinary ones or vice versa.

For more context, I have an old codebase that still uses `java.util.Timer` for scheduled tasks, and an application-wide `ThreadPoolExecutor` for ordinary tasks. Since `Timer` is single-threaded, our TimerTasks typically shift computation immediately to the thread pool once the Timer executes them, in order not to delay further TimerTasks. Something along these lines:

```java
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
    executor.execute(this::performWork);
  }
}, 1000);
```

So far we postponed refactoring from `Timer` to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, but it's only now that I realize that we can eliminate constructs like the one above when using a single thread pool for all kinds of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using two separate pools for two reasons. The first reason is that I find it easier from an application perspective to tune the pools if they are distinct. It is probably easier to predict the number of threads needed for scheduled tasks and for one-shot tasks than the combined workload.
The second reason is from the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited
> tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as
> a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue,
> adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect. Additionally,
> it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use
> allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads
> to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

In other words it doesn't quite behave as a regular ThreadPoolExecutor and tuning efforts can have surprising effects including starvation.

Comment: Interesting! What if the tuning turns out to be similar, or if there is very little load on the scheduled tasks? Would you still recommend two separate pools? In any case, I will probably provide two different methods for getting an appropriate pool. Then I can later change whether they point to the same pool or not.

Comment: You probably don't want a fixed-size pool for your normal tasks, so yes the recommendation stands.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I misinterpreted the fact that Integer.MAX_VALUE is passed for `maximumPoolSize` to the super constructor, which indeed has no effect.

Comment: And for completeness' sake, what do you think of the strategy of forwarding the actual execution of the scheduled task to another pool? Is that good, bad, or just not worth it? If it is a good idea, I could create a wrapper `ScheduledExecutorService` which would handle this transparently.

Comment: You could do that. It might be good depending on your application. If the tasks can be long-running it is good not to tie up one of the threads in the fixed-size scheduled pool. The main downsides would be extra complexity and a very slight performance hit when the tasks are handed to the other pool.